# Skeptics Stack Exchange, and its relationship with "Poisoning the Well"

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, editing, moderators

### Question

What ought to be the relationship between "Skeptics" and those "Skeptics" who intentionally go out and "poison the well", particularly on behalf of other people's answers?

> Poisoning the well (or attempting to poison the well) is a type of informal fallacy where adverse information about a target is preemptively presented to an audience, with the intention of discrediting or ridiculing something that the target person is about to say. Poisoning the well can be a special case of argumentum ad hominem

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well

---

### Backstory [ You can skip to "Underlying Principle" ]

<sub>I am going to go into depth, with the purpose of covering all the bases for this particular instance because it was done so by the moderator.</sub>

I recently came back to my answer here: [Did Jeffrey Epstein take his own life?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/did-jeffrey-epstein-take-his-own-life/54359#54359)

@Oddthinking made these particular edits, where he added context to two figures in question:

> [Far-right podcaster, Stefan Molyneux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Molyneux)

> [Alt-Right Social Media Personality, Mike Cernovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Cernovich)

---

### How do you know this was the intent to "Poison the well" behind the edit? 
<sub>Perhaps he simply wanted to add some clarification or context?</sub>

It was followed up by this comment:

> It is ironic that one answer has a comment complaining that the official findings are "hearsay", but this answer relies eOntirely on the "expertise" of Stefan Molyneux **of all people** - it comes across as an advert for **a racist nut job.** If, as claimed, Molyneaux provides references to support **his conspiracy theories**, then please follow them up an cite them here. We should not be expected to **sit through hours of hateful nonsense** just to see if there is any evidence included.  – Oddthinking ♦ Feb 8 at 5:24

Demonstrating the intent behind his edits. He also politely threatened me prior to posting the answer:

> @Anon: Then this site is clearly not for you. Thanks for stopping by. No-one should attempt to answer the Epstein question here without adhering to scientific skepticism. –
> Oddthinking Mod Feb 7 at 23:12

When I asked what the consequences were:

> Deletion of the post and, if a user is insistent on ignoring the standards required, suspension, are the consequences. – Nij Feb 12 at 1:06

And @Oddthinking left this edit comment in my answer, where he removed a postscript I left citing the previous polite threat:

> Take your **epistemological sophistry** and desire to change the entire purpose of this SE to Meta.

---

### But how exactly is this poisoning the well?

<sub>He just linked the Wikipedia articles so we know who these people are?</sub>

@Oddthinking chose to use the terms "Alt Right" and "Far Right":

- First, "Alt Right" happens to contradict the very wikipedia article cited:

> Michael Cernovich (born November 17, 1977) is an American right-wing social media personality, political commentator, and conspiracy theorist. Though he initially called himself alt-right, **he dissociated from the movement after Richard Spencer became its public face**. Cernovich describes himself as part of the **new right and some have described him as part of the alt-lite.**

- This demonstrates that @Oddthinking is intent on associating MC with Richard Spencer who is more or less an avowed white supremacist. The moderator chose the most scandalous and pejorative label available. He also editted the answer to imply that Mike Cernovich was not involved with the case under the reasoning that he had nothing to do with the initial arrest of Epstein.

---

- Second, "Far-right" on the other hand is **literally a one dimensional analysis,** wherein figures like Adolf Hitler share the exact same designation, which is more or less a rhetorical device.

  - Stefan Molyneux does not self describe as far right.
  - He has self described as Libertarian, Atheist, Objectivist, Anarchist, Philosopher.
  - He explicitly makes the case against being "Far Right" here: https://www.bitchute.com/video/vKCYmgvlar0/

  Description:

  > Showing the lack of respect they have for the intelligence of their audience, the mainstream media often attaches "bucket" labels to criticize individuals instead of using actual arguments. Stefan Molyneux looks at a recent Business Insider article which called Ann Coulter, Mike Cernovich, Steve Bannon's Breitbart and himself "Far-Right" while describing their opposition to the war in Afghanistan. **Who knew that opposing war and western imperialism was a far-right position!**

Even if we ought to accept that type of broad categorization, the wikipedia lead that @Oddthinking links to, starts off with this:

> is an Irish-born Canadian far-right **white nationalist**[2][3][4][5] and **white supremacist**[6][7][8] podcaster, blogger, author, political commentator, and banned YouTuber who promotes conspiracy theories, **scientific racism**, men's rights, and **racist views**.[15] He is the founder of the Freedomain Radio website.[1] As of September 2020, Molyneux has been permanently banned or permanently suspended from PayPal, Mailchimp, YouTube, and SoundCloud, all for **violating hate speech policies**.[16][17][18][19][20]

1. The bold here does poison the well and are unfair characterizations. They are pejoratives that are well known to illicit feelings of fear, uncertainty, and doubt.

   - Unfair for example, that ***permanently suspended from PayPal, Mailchimp, YouTube, and SoundCloud, all for violating hate speech policies*** lacks the context that the bans were unjust or unsubstantiated, and were arbitrarily applied for the purposes of political censorship.
2. None of the bold conforms to any self description, and has been repeatedly and consistently argued against.
3. All of the propositions in bold, are considered extremely controversial and in doubt, as evidenced by the talk page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Stefan_Molyneux/Archive_11#Semi-protected_edit_request_on_13_December_2020

---

### The wikipedia article has citations. 
<sub>Isn't that fair game?</sub>

The wikipedia articles on political figures are notoriously unreliable given this:

- [Has or does SE suffer from shills or cabals of special interest groups looking to peddle influence or control narrative?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320109/has-or-does-se-suffer-from-shills-or-cabals-of-special-interest-groups-looking-t)

One simply needs to accept that the consequences of political fallout perpetually drives forth propaganda campaigns towards that which is influential:

1. Stefan Molyneux prior to deplatforming, was influential.
2. Wikipedia still is influential.
3. A cabal formed [formally and informally] to deplatform Stefan Molyneux, and used his wikipedia lead to help accomplish this.
4. He is subsequently unfairly attacked, as with the case of @Oddthinking characterizing him

> a racist nutjob full of hours of hateful nonsense

Which is unsubstantiated.

---

### But what about the issue of Whitewashing? 
<sub>People ought to be informed of the substance of a person's character or qualification.</sub>

- I was subscribed to Stefan Molyneux for a long time.
- He was never properly "hateful" in any conventional sense, except in the case early on with his relationship to Christians and Christianity. [ None of that hatred is cited in his wikipedia article. ]

  - He later on recanted and apologised for that.

What has perpetually characterized his positions were the *Non Aggression Principle*, and how he applied that to daily life. For example he made countless videos regarding the importance of "Peaceful Parenting":

Here he advocates against ever spanking a child:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSzK-ydSdo4

Here he holds a roundtable for "Peaceful Parenting"

- https://www.bitchute.com/video/cGdyimfK0Z6q/

Here he talks with his daughter on the idea of Friendship

- https://www.bitchute.com/video/MgTmaV1C6eiC/

No one could reasonably watch any of those videos and conclude

> a racist nutjob full of hours of hateful nonsense

because agree or disagree with his positions, he is polite with his guests, has a soft temperment, and almost holistically appeals to reason and evidence.

---

### The problem is not those videos. 
<sub>It is the videos where he speaks about Race.</sub>

Here he speaks about Race & IQ with Jared Taylor.

https://www.bitchute.com/video/YSB8xFt19JSL/

Description:

> For years and years, many have proclaimed a desire for an honest conversation about race, but fiercely object when such a discussion is attempted. Stefan Molyneux is joined by Jared Taylor for a discussion about racial tensions around the world and “The Color of Crime,” which is an incredibly well-researched report on differences in crime rates by race, bias in the justice system, and interracial crime statistics.

The video is neither "Hateful", or full of "Nutjobs". Data is provided, and they provide an analysis, and Stefan's position can be summed up as,

> One ought to be able to talk about data pertaining to race, without being held responsible for why that data exists.

---

### This question is just "an advert for a racist nut job [Stefan Molyneux]."

This is a truism. Its like saying an answer that cites Snopes, is just a big advertisement for "Snopes".

---

### Underlying Principle

In my answer [https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/did-jeffrey-epstein-take-his-own-life/54359#54359], I "poison the well" myself here:

> The doctor is a personal friend of his [ Implying bias ]

> Here, Molyneux also reviews this as an admitted amateur

> You can consider him to be an actor tertiary to this case, and not formally involved.

I think all of those are contextually important to the answer.

Being generous, I may even consider the label, "Far Right" to be tangentially relevant because Epstein was a "Far Left" Wing figure, implying bias on behalf of SM.

But the terms,

1. Alt Right
2. Conspiracy Theorist
3. Racist Nutjob
4. White Nationalist
5. White Supremacist
6. Hateful

Which were attached to my answer by @Oddthinking, has absolutely nothing to do with one's veracity to address the topic of whether or not Jeffery Epstein's death was in fact a homicide.

While I take it in good humor that its more or less to be expected that political acolytes  will employ these sorts of tactics as a matter of sport, but it still strikes me as being a disavowal of good humor and common sense, and more aptly, of "Scientific Skepticism" which the aforementioned has gone to great lengths to lecture me upon.

And so to reiterate my question:

> What ought to be the relationship between "Skeptics" and those "Skeptics" who intentionally go out and "poison the well", particularly on behalf of other people's answers?

Should this behaviour be allowed, or discouraged?

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a rant about your opinions on how an answer got handled.

Answer (score 8):

I don't want to waste too much time on this question.

I should just say `If you have a complaint about a moderator, use the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page.', and walk away.

---

> What ought to be the relationship between "Skeptics" and those "Skeptics" who intentionally go out and "poison the well", particularly on behalf of other people's answers?

This isn't an answerable question.

---

I edited in links into to give context to whom Stefan Molyneux and Mike Cernovich were. (I had to look them up myself - their names were vaguely familiar and I needed reminding) I linked to their Wikipedia page because I don't think the facts of who they are were in dispute and needed justifying. I summarised what I saw there. The terms Far-Right and Alt-Right came from those pages. In the 24 hours after I linked, the Mike Cernovich page was edited back and forth to avoid the term Alt-Right.

I think including context is important, and often edit pages to add links to people's Wikipedia page, because (1) it is common for answerers to have a parochial view of the world, and not realise that we have readers from around the world who might not know the names of local "celebrities", and (2) to establish whether the reference is (like in this case) to some opinion site or whether it is to some relevant authority. Molyneux and Cernovich are not relevant authorities.

---

While I stand by my opinion (shared in a comment) that Molyneux is a racist nutjob (which is an opinion supported by the evidence on his Wikipedia page), when I first saw a comment from @Anon suggesting it was poisoning the well, I did reconsider it. It wasn't poisoning the well, on a technicality (it came *after* the relevant argument). However, it was a political opinion. While the overall comment was intended to improve the answer, it probably didn't need to be shared. I was still pondering whether to edit it or remove it and repost the comment (next time I had access to a real keyboard) when this diatribe posing as a meta-question went up.

---

I reject that Far-Right and Alt-Right are pejoratives. They are political positions, and useful context when digesting the videos.

---

> This is a truism. Its like saying an answer that cites Snopes, is just a big advertisement for "Snopes".

The answer had several links, but each was to the same commentator. It made no attempt to follow up his evidence to see how he justified his claims with empirical evidence. That is why it read more like spam than an answer.

---

The whole "Molyneux was never mean to me, and he is good with kids" argument is irrelevant, and reads as a second attempt at spam. After all, Epstein collected art, played the piano, and ran a charitable foundation - doesn't mean he was innocent.

---

The other attacks against me in this question were shown out of context:

I *did* say this:

> @Anon: Then this site is clearly not for you. Thanks for stopping by. No-one should attempt to answer the Epstein question here without adhering to scientific skepticism. – Oddthinking Mod Feb 7 at 23:12

but you have omitted the part where you declined to accept Scientific Skepticism as the appropriate approach to answering questions, making your repeated claims to be a "skeptic" inaccurate by the definitions used here.

When you claimed this statement was a *threat*, I realised I was talking to someone who was not arguing in good faith, and declined to reply to the question with the obvious answer - you already know what penalties moderators can impose, and know that they don't extend to being locked in a prison cell with no guards monitoring you, or anything else you can be reasonably threatened by.

I also did remove your inappropriate attempt **in an answer** to attack me and try to derail the site with epistemological sophistry, and recommended you took it to Meta, where the community could evaluate it.

Your attempts to do so have no been received well by the community. Good luck with that in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I have deleted your answer now because it is essentially unreferenced. A YouTube video by Stefan Molyneux is not a reliable reference.

As Oddthinking explained in his first comment on your answer, if there are real references in the video you're free to use them and make an answer out of them. The YouTube video itself is not a good reference, it's pretty much the same as linking a random website by some random person. Your references need to have a minimum of credibility, otherwise you could always satisfy the reference requirements by linking any random website.

Another important part that makes the video a bad reference is that it contains a very large number of claims. You have a lot of specific claims in your post, but the main reference is just to the video. This makes it very difficult to follow your references, as they're all combined.

The last part that makes your referencing problematic is that many statements are not about the actual facts of the death of Epstein. They are about potential motivations to kill him, with a heavy conspiracy theory vibe. This would not be much of a problem on its own, but it adds to the overall issue.

Your answer is also heavily downvoted, so the community does not find it convincing.

Comment: The videos were referenced. What do I need to do to get them undeleted? Simply provide better referencing in the answer? Otherwise I just see this as blatant censorship of the positive position on homicide, or revenge for being critical of the moderating team.

Comment: It's not a YouTube video. It's a Bitchute video. I don't know about anyone else but I will not visit those links due to the platform hosting hate speech and even more objectionable videos. That's even more reason why any evidence, if it exists, needs to be in the answer.

Comment: @Laurel What does a view being objectionable have anything to do with the veracity of answer?

Comment: @Anon Because (if you don't include enough information from the video in the answer) the veracity of the answer can't be determined if I don't click on the link. And I'm not clicking on the link. (I'm not the only one who does this. I've heard of people who avoid Google and Facebook for various reasons, mostly security.)

Comment: @Laurel `if you don't include enough information from the video in the answer` This is a bluff: the video description was quoted along with a synopsis. `I'm not the only one who does this.` Two wrongs do not make a right. A genuine skeptic has the integrity to listen to what they may otherwise consider objectionable, and to do so with love, empathy, and consideration all those involved.