# What exactly does "Essentially unreferenced" mean when references were provided?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, deletion, moderators

A moderator [posted](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4932/30694) the following regarding [this Answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/54359/30694):

> I have deleted your answer now because it is essentially unreferenced. A YouTube video by Stefan Molyneux is not a reliable reference.

This statement is fundamentally vague, and **crafted to justify moderation abuse**:

> it is essentially unreferenced.

Every video which was linked, was referenced.

- https://www.bitchute.com/video/GVHt7LwHP3c/ - Referencing the Gateway pundit. [ Though no link is provided ]
- https://www.bitchute.com/video/mtiV0VJsc9c/ - https://www.takimag.com/article/media-magic-how-a-democrat-pedophile-became-a-trump-scandal/
- https://www.bitchute.com/video/lzYgdlMzr_s/ - Is speaking with a medical professional asking for his opinion. His contact info is provided.
- https://www.bitchute.com/video/BJTBG5eWuJs/ - https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7855039/Graphic-photos-Jeffrey-Epsteins-autopsy-reveal-bloodied-neck.html & https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/ricky-gervais-golden-globes-monologue-gets-political-1266308
- https://www.bitchute.com/video/P955jlxAoUY/ - https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/tycoon-paedo-jeffrey-epsteins-butler-4930850

And that is that.

> A YouTube video

It is simply a medium like any other, and it was not devoid of descriptions, a synopsis, or of the underlying reasoning.

> Stefan Molyneux is not a reliable reference.

[Ipse dixit.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipse_dixit)

To wit, he is very "reliable", though you may despise him, because:

1. He routinely subjects himself to criticism and has open debates with any virtually any detractor. [ Unlike any of the fact checking websites ]
2. He ironically writes books on being "reliable", most notably:
   [https://www.amazon.com/Art-Argument-Western-Civilizations-Stand-ebook/dp/B0756QYZ26](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0756QYZ26)

> 'The Art of the Argument' shocks the dying art of rational debate back to life, giving you the essential tools you need to fight the escalating sophistry, falsehoods and vicious personal attacks that have displaced intelligent conversations throughout the world. At a time when we need reasonable and empirical discussions more desperately than ever, 'The Art of the Argument' smashes through the brain-eating fogs of sophistry and mental manipulation, illuminating a path to benevolent power for all who wish to take it.

---

### Why do you think he is "abusing" his moderating status?

1. The current "Skeptics" SE paradigm is hostile to right wing positions:

   - The moderating team expresses, or acts in accordance to left leaning positons. For example, a comment was left stating that SM [Right wing] was a "Racist nutjob", which is completely an unfair characterization.
   - They abide by a principle called, "Scientific Skepticism", which is more of a rhetorical device than an epistemelogical one. In short, its used to devise conclusions suitable to fit a left wing narrative by picking and choosing who can be an authority, and who can not be.
   - The only answer affirming homicide of Jeffery Epstein, has now been deleted.
2. I am critical of the current paradigm of this Stack Exchange as it is not sufficiently "Skeptical", respectfully.
3. I am politically heterodox, and am therefore a political pariah.
4. Because this is a SE committed to skeptics, **censorship or deletion of heterodox answers is an abuse of moderation.**

Comment: Re `Edit` Apologies. I did not know about that rule and thought it was fair game to call out abusive moderators. It will not happen again.

Answer (score 6):

If you think a moderator is abusing their powers you need to use the contact button at the bottom of the page to contact stack exchange themselves. When you do this you need to explain what you think is wrong and they will investigate and take action as needed.

Here is the link for you.

https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 6):

Let me introduce some other Stack Exchanges:

- https://mathoverflow.net/
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/
- https://law.stackexchange.com/
- https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/
- https://economics.stackexchange.com/
- https://islam.stackexchange.com/
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/
- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/
- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/
- https://history.stackexchange.com/
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Each of these sites represents a community dedicated to finding the truth and discarding bad ideas. Each of these sites goes about it with their own methodology. If you don't want to use that methodology, your contributions won't be welcomed.

Quoting the Bhagavad Gita won't get you far on Physics.SE. Quoting Richard Dawkins won't get you far on Islam.SE. Dismissing hearsay evidence won't get you far on History.SE. Demanding experimental evidence won't get you far on Literature.SE.

You can call that censorship if you like, but... you won't get far - they will call it moderation. These communities have met together because of their dedication to a particular methodology, and if you don't like it, they don't have to stop. You can go somewhere else.

Skeptics.SE is another one of those sites. It is, as explained in the second sentence of the [tour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour):

> a question and answer site for applying scientific skepticism.

You have explained that you don't want to be limited to scientific skepticism. You have explained you think it is biased to the left-wing.

I have explained that, if that represents your position, this may not be the site for you, and that any answers to that Epstein question should apply Scientific Skepticism.

You have ignored that, posted a poor answer, had it heavily downvoted by the community, had many comments explaining its flaws and what you can do to fix it, largely ignored those comments, eventually had the answer deleted, and are now posting a "Shocked Pikachu" meta-question complaining about your treatment.

---

As to the question in the title, I refer to the comments given on you answer, from me and three others, including:

> If, as claimed, Molyneaux provides references to support his conspiracy theories, then please follow them up an cite them here. We should not be expected to sit through hours of hateful nonsense just to see if there is any evidence included.

> "Every single anomaly would be satisfied" This is a nonsense assertion, and ignores all the existing evidence that would suddenly become anomalies. Calling homicide a "rather simple explanation" ignores that it is too vague. Tell us who and how and when - not just the murder but the cover up. While your conjecture remains vague, you can constantly morph it in an attempt to explain anomalies. If you tried to make in into a concrete single explanation, it would likely fail to explain all the evidence.

> This "answer" merely lists accusations by a right-wing podcaster, and doesn't cite any evidence to back up the podcaster's claims.

> When reading through this answer, I keep getting hit by Occam’s razor in that there are far more probable answers than a conspiracy. Other times, the list seems to be connecting things that aren’t connected. So, this definitely needs some evidence to back these statements up, a list of supposed evidence isn’t evidence itself.

> The 5th and 21st bullet points are direct contradictions. The 5th bullet point claims he was suicidal, the 21st bullet point claims he wasn't.

---

Once again, I haven't spend too much time answering this question. Your meta-questions have been a little scattergun with their claims and I can't warrant replying in detail to each one.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143236/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-what-exactly-does-essentially-unreferenced); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.